# No boot on encrypted drive 16.04 - help pls?

Tags: boot, encryption

I can't boot to my 16.04
My drive is encrypted, see details here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MGMMQMzZcH/

```
Device     Boot   Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423    997376   487M 83 Linux

/dev/sda2       1001470 1000214527 999213058 476.5G  5 Extended

/dev/sda5       1001472 1000214527 999213056 476.5G 83 Linux
```

I have two questions:

1. I am desperate to fix it, but not sure how exactly to do so?
2. How to access data on /dev/sda5?

Thanks in advance!